# How to check that $f(t,x)\ge 0$ for any $x\ge 0$?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, fractional-calculus

Suppose $f(t,x)$ satisfices $\partial_t f=\Lambda^{-\alpha}f\partial_xf$, for $0<\alpha<1$ and where $\Lambda=(-\partial_{xx})^{1/2}$, $f_0(x)=f(0,x)$ is odd, and $f_0(x)\ge 0$, $\forall x\ge 0$. We can directly check that $-f(t,-x)$ is also a solution. Therefore, $f(t,x)$ is odd in $x$ by the uniqueness of solutions for the above PDE.

**My Question:** How does one check that $f(t,x)\geq  0$ for all $x\ge 0$?

Remark: this question is a detail in Lemma 4.1 of [On a one-dimensional -patch model with nonlocal drift and fractional dissipation](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2014-366-04/S0002-9947-2013-06075-8/S0002-9947-2013-06075-8.pdf).